# Setting parameter invoked Method

Tags: reflection, compact-framework, invoke

I have a question about .Net CF 3.5 Reflection.I am invoking expected something method like this,

```
        object n=  instance.Type.GetMethod("DoSome"
            ).Invoke(instance.Instance,
            new object[] { commandKeys }
            );
```

commandKey is my parameter list, instance.Type and instance.Instance is not null.
Methods invokes normally but, when I set any property(belongs to which I am calling class) in "DoSome" method, property dont have a value(default value).

```
 public class CSet:ITask
{
  public void DoSome
{
   SomeProperty=true;
   OnTaskCompleted(this);


}
}
```

I am catching "OnTaskCompleted" delegate which contains "ITask" interface but like i said ITask SomeProperty has not my given value

Thx your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You say that the "Methods invokes normally", but at the same time you claim that the code inside the method is not executed. How do you know that the method is invoked at all?

Are you sure that `instance.Instace` is the same instance you check `SomeProperty` on, and catch `OnTaskCompleted` from?

Comment: I didnt say "method not executed".Method invokes, but in the invoke method i am setting a property after that i see property has not my given value, it not changed.Also i am sure instance.Instace is same that all invoke operation.